# error: conflicting types for user made function in c program

Tags: c

```
// the same error does not happen if i use int instead of float in function. 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

  {

float a;
printf("\nEnter any number");

scanf("%f",&a);

float b = sq(a);

printf("\nthe square of %f is %f",a,b);

}

float sq(float x)

{

float y;

y = x*x;

return y;

}
//error: conflicting type for sq
```

Comment: Use a C99/C11 compiler or raise your warning levels.

Answer (score 4):

The first time the compiler encounters `sq()` is in `main()`. At that point, the compiler has no way of knowing what the function's return type is. What the compiler(*) does is assume that `sq()` returns `int`. This assumption is incorrect since the function returns `float`. This results in the error you are seeing.

Either move `sq()` to appear above `main()`, or insert the following [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) before `main()`:

```
float sq(float x);
```

(*) Note that this only applies to pre-[C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) compilers since this behaviour has been removed in C99.

Comment: @mafso: Is `double` a typo, or am I missing some subtlety here?

Answer (score 0):

[valid code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP7PD.png)

In GCC compiler we have to put function before it call by main Function